# Cannot install java?

Tags: java, jdk

Edit: This is Ubuntu 13.04

Before I begin, I've seen this question around,

```
 sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

It tells me

```
... ect .. ect (Failed to fetch)
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/icedtea-7-jre-jamvm_7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.13.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

so then I run

```
sudo apt-get --fix-missing install openjdk-7-jdk
```

and it tells me that it still cant fetch and unable to correct missing.

```
I also run sudo apt-get update to no affect.
```

Any ideas?

Installing java, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 13.04 has reached it End of Life(EOL) and its repositories have been moved to an archive server. Use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) link to change your sources to the archive server.

However, I would advise you to install a supported version, ie Ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10.

Comment: Thanks! Ill accept this answer soon. Yeah this way just downloaded through my VM Ill make sure to upgrade.